# Spring boot push notification to vue.js

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, push-notification, spring-websocket, stomp

I want to send notification to all client connected using websocket and webstomp ,so I need to push notification when some row added to database , I tried something like this but did not work

my socket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/socket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

controller

```
template.convertAndSend("/topic/notification", position);
```

front

```
methods: {
    connect() {
        this.socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8082/socket");
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
        this.stompClient.connect({},
           frame => {
             this.connected = true;
             console.log(frame);
             this.stompClient.subscribe("/topic/notification", tick => {
               console.log(tick);
               this.$notify({
                 group: 'foo',
                 title: '<h4>Nothing!</h4>',
                 text: 'car added',
                 type: 'success',
                 duration: 1000
              })
          });
       },
       error => {
         console.log(error);
         this.connected = false;
       }
     );
   },
 },
```

Comment: Can you show the exact error? from console or logs. It is hard to say something without errors

Comment: I didn't get any error but didn't get any notification

Comment: have you seen the browser console logs?